# Adding the same vector to two linear independent sets and form a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, change-of-basis

the question is as follows:

In vector space $V$ with $dim(V) = 4$, there are two sets of linear independent vectors:

$S = \{v1, v2, v3\}$

$R = \{u1, u2, u3\}$

Prove that exists $v \in V$ such as $ S \cup v $ and $W \cup v $ are both basis for $V$.

I tried to add a vector to complete $S$ to a basis of $V$, and then try to represent $u1, u2, u3$ with this basis, but couldn't proceed much further.

Any ideas?

Comment: Take $v$ not in $\mathrm{span}(S)\cap \mathrm{span}(R).$

Comment: @mfl I tried to do it, but it's obvious isn't it? Since $v$ should be linear independent to the vectors already in $S$ and $R$

Comment: @mfl Is that sufficient? Take $V = \mathbb{R}^4, S = \{e_1,e_2,e_3\}, R = \{e_2,e_3,e_4\}$. Then there certainly vectors which are in the complement of the intersection of the spans that do not form a basis for $V$ with both $S$ and $R$, i.e. $e_1$

Comment: For your particular $S$ and $R$ just consider $v=e_1+e_4$ (assuming $e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4$ are linearly independent).

Comment: Why is this true? I’m trying to understand the logic behind this choosing